# What are the new JVM arguments introduces in Java8?

Tags: java-8

Very basic but can any one tell me what are the new JVM arguments introduces in Java8?

I am not able to find any concrete list over net.

Comment: maybe this can be useful? -> http://www.baeldung.com/jvm-parameters

Comment: see [this](http://www.baeldung.com/jvm-parameters)

Comment: i already checked this.it covers all?

Comment: are there any advantages to having that list? *I would rather be looking for a list with a detailed explanation of each argument*

Answer (score 1):

I know about a few of them only (that I got to use), like:

```
-parameters (for named parameters)
```

Since the addition of meta-space, these were added (used only a few of them)

```
InitialBootClassLoaderMetaspaceSize 
MaxMetaspaceExpansion
MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio
MaxMetaspaceSize
MetaspaceSize
MinMetaspaceExpansion 
MinMetaspaceFreeRatio
UseLargePagesInMetaspace
```

And one about lambda usage:

```
-Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses = /Some/Path
```

I only vaguely know about these two:

```
MinHeapFreeRatio
MaxHeapFreeRatio
```

I am absolutely sure there are many more...

Comment: @NullPointer well, the correct answer would be that the JVM options are *implementation specific*, so it makes no sense to ask for JVM options specific to the Java *language version*. While it surely is correct that a particular implementation like Oracle’s HotSpot JVM introduced new options with the Java 8 release, there is no guaranty that, e.g. IBM’s JVM has the same options when supporting Java 8. Or perhaps, it already had the some of these options in a previous version.